# translation.warning with list item in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, translation

Currently on Symfony2, I had log message such as *translation.WARNING: Translation not found. {"id":"Electronique","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"} []* corresponding to list item.

Any ideas how to avoid this log message ?

Thanks

Comment: It's a bit difficult without any information ;)

Comment: the list item contains (music) items like 'Electronique', 'Rnb', 'Techno'... For all these items, I have this type of message